# Why am getting errors while passing argumets from commad line image file as an argument

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

```
 import argparse

 from PIL import Image

 from pytesseract import *


def image_to_text(image):

   pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

   result = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, lang='eng')

   return result

if __name__ == "__main__":

  ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

  ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", type = open, required = True, help='path to input image')

  args = vars(ap.parse_args())

  img = Image.open(ap)

  print(image_to_text(img))
```

After executing this code using command line arguments passing parameter as image as input am getting the following errors.Please help me why these are occuring.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2972, in open

```
fp.seek(0)
```

AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'seek'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\Desktop\image\code.py", line 18, in

```
img = Image.open(ap)
```

File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2974, in open

```
fp = io.BytesIO(fp.read())
```

AttributeError: 'ArgumentParser' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Add a `print(args)` line so you can see exactly what the parser has done.

Answer (score 1):

`ap` is the argument parser.  It is not a file name, so you can't pass it as a file name.  You should remove `type=open`, because you don't really want arg parser to open it, then change the Image line to

```
 args = ap.parse_args()
 img = Image.open(args.input)
```

You want the RESULT of the parsing, not the parser itself.  That is, `args.input` will contain the filename that was specified in the `--input` parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting the followinng errors after changing the answer C:\Users\Chaitanya\Desktop\image>code.py --input imagetotext.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chaitanya\Desktop\image\code.py", line 18, in <module>
    img = Image.open(args.input)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'input'

Comment: I should have noticed you were using `vars()`.  That is totally unnecessary here.  Just leave it as an object.  It's more convenient, anyway.  I tweaked my answer.